# Keeping count of Java recursive calls (Find the GCD)

Tags: java, recursion

I'm unable to match the same output in my class for this recursive java program. For the integers `76` and `84` the number of recursive calls should be 3, but I am getting 4. Is my prof's sample output wrong?

```
package Week13;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment12_Part1 {
    static int counter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        counter = 0;

        System.out.print("Please enter two integers space seperated: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = input.nextInt();
        int b = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The GCD of " + a + " and " + b + " is " + gcd(a, b));
        System.out.printf("Total %4d recursive calls", counter);
        input.close();
    }

    public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
        counter++;
        if (b == 0) return a;
        else if (a == 0) return b;
        else if (a % b == 0) return b;
        else return gcd(b, a % b);
    }

}
```

Comment: It depends on the order of the numbers.  If you enter the smaller one first, it will take one additional call.  If you enter the larger one first, it will take 3 calls.

Comment: In our sample output, the smaller number was input first and the count is 3.

Comment: Well, perhaps you're putting the counter in the wrong spot.  You are counting as soon as you enter.  But that first time is not a recursive call.  The other thing you can do is put in some print statements to see what the state of the variables are as the gcd is being calculated.  But the algorithm seems to be working fine.